# convert array of full date to array of month in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

i try to convert array of date to array of month in react

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import moment from "moment";
const LinkChart = () => {
const link = [
"2021-01-19T18:11:33.383Z", 
"2021-03-19T18:11:40.617Z", 
"2021-04-19T18:11:47.894Z", 
"2021-05-19T18:11:53.305Z", 
"2021-06-19T18:11:55.341Z", 
"2021-07-19T18:11:59.325Z", 
"2021-07-20T07:05:29.877Z", 
"2021-07-21T09:02:08.691Z"]
    const [clicks,] = useState(link.clicks);
    const [clickDate,setClickDate] = useState([]);
    const [month,setMonth] = useState([]);


    useEffect(()=>{
            setClickDate(link.clicksDate);

            clickDate.map((l,index)=>{
                let months = []
                const convertedDateToMonths = moment(l).format('MMM');
                months.push(convertedDateToMonths) 
                return setMonth(months);
            })
    },[link,clickDate])
    
    return <>

    </>
}

export default LinkChart;
```

when i push convertedDateToMonths to array every time i rewrite month
in output i got only 1 month when i do console.log(month)
what i do wrong ?

Comment: You want `setMonth(clickDate.map(l => moment(l).format('MMM')))` instead of most of your code

Comment: @CherryDT thanks you very much it help me very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `setMonth` function with the updated table and not on each `.map` loop. So just process the links with a simple map to get the list of months and call `setMonth` with the result of it:

```
const LinkChart = () => {
  const LINKS = [
    "2021-01-19T18:11:33.383Z",
    "2021-03-19T18:11:40.617Z",
    "2021-04-19T18:11:47.894Z",
    "2021-05-19T18:11:53.305Z",
    "2021-06-19T18:11:55.341Z",
    "2021-07-19T18:11:59.325Z",
    "2021-07-20T07:05:29.877Z",
    "2021-07-21T09:02:08.691Z"
  ];
  const [months, setMonths] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMonths(
      LINKS.map((l) => {
        return moment(l).format("MMM");
      })
    );
  }, [LINKS]);

  // ...
};
```

[image: Edit modern-waterfall-c20vi]

Answer (score 1):

I'm just correcting couple things to optimize from existing answer. LINKS is a constant and doesn't have to be within the component. No `useEffect` needed as adding the LINKS as dependency will add unnecessary re-renders (Object.is comparison on Array). Use a lazy state initialization (this assumes that the LINK is static as per your code. If its dynamic from props, then you need to watch out for re-renders)

**If LINKS is static:**

```
const LINKS = [
    "2021-01-19T18:11:33.383Z",
    "2021-03-19T18:11:40.617Z",
    "2021-04-19T18:11:47.894Z",
    "2021-05-19T18:11:53.305Z",
    "2021-06-19T18:11:55.341Z",
    "2021-07-19T18:11:59.325Z",
    "2021-07-20T07:05:29.877Z",
    "2021-07-21T09:02:08.691Z"   ]; 

const LinkChart = () => {
const [months, setMonths] = useState(() => LINKS.map((link) => moment(link).format("MMM")));
.
.
.// rest of your code
};
```

**If LINK is dynamic:**(assuming as a prop)

```
const LinkChart = ({links}) => {
  const allLinkMonths = links.map((link) => moment(link).format("MMM"));
  const [months, setMonths] = useState(allLinkMonths);

  useEffect(() => {
   // write a method to check if months modified. Not using array dependency as its a complicated dependency
   if(isLinkMonthsChanged(months, allLinkMonths)){
     setMonths(allLinkMonths);
   }
  });
.
.
.// rest of your code
};
```

Comment: thank you very much it's really help to me

Answer (score 1):

**What's wrong with your code**:

- You're redeclaring `months` on every iteration of `map` to an empty array.
- You're using `map` to iterate an array and not create a new one (use `forEach` or classic `for` for your push-on-every-iteration approach).

**How I would implement the function**:

```
const getMonthsFromLinks(links) {
  return links.map((link) => moment(link).format('MMM'));
}
```

**Set months in your component**

```
const monthsList = getMonthsFromLinks(LINKS);
setMonths(monthsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

you're re-initiate the month every loop. It's become empty array every loop and only save the last month only in the end